# deduce the type of tuple elements in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code.

```
template <typename... Types>
void print_tuple(const std::tuple<Types&&...>& value)
{
    std::cout << std::get<0>(value) << "," << std::get<1>(value) << std::endl;
}
print_tuple(std::forward_as_tuple("test",1));
```

which compiler complains about

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const std::tuple<const char (&&)[5], int&&>&’ from expression of type ‘std::tuple<const char (&)[5], int&&>’
     print_tuple(std::forward_as_tuple("test",1));
```

why does compiler deduce the type of the first element in the tuple to be const char (&&)[5]?

Comment: You don't even need to capture a tuple specifically. Why not simply `template<class Tuple> void print_tuple(Tuple&& value)`?

Comment: Since it wasn't clear to at least two people: your `print_tuple` definition *does* allow the call if the template arguments are explicitly specified as `print_tuple<const char(&)[5], int>`. It's a good question why the compiler is deducing the first `Types` differently.

Comment: @hvd It could be because a string literal is an lvalue and is being forwarded as such.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I understand that it's an lvalue. That's how I could figure out that it works if writing `const char(&)[5]`. But the question, I think, is why the compiler cannot figure that out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, for deduction to succeed, the argument needs to have the same general form as the parameter. There are some exceptions where `T &&` can be deduced from `U &` (by selecting `T = U &`), but no such exception was specified for this case.

> **14.8.2.5 Deducing template arguments from a type [temp.deduct.type]**
>
> 8 A template type argument `T`, a template template argument `TT` or a template non-type argument `i` can be deduced if `P` and `A` have one of the following forms:
>
> [...]
>
> `T&`
> `T&&`
>
> [...]

It's not exactly clear, but this requires `P` (the parameter) and `A` (the argument) to both have the same form. They need to both be of the `T&` form, or both of the `T&&` form. The exceptions, the circumstances where `T &&` can be deduced from `U &`, are done by changing `T &&` to plain `T` before the matching takes place, in limited circumstances:

> 10 Similarly, if `P` has a form that contains `(T)`, then each parameter type `Pi` of the respective *parameter-type-list* of `P` is compared with the corresponding parameter type `Ai` of the corresponding *parameter-type-list* of `A`. If `P` and `A` are function types that originated from deduction when taking the address of a function template (14.8.2.2) or when deducing template arguments from a function declaration (14.8.2.6) and `Pi` and
> `Ai` are parameters of the top-level *parameter-type-list* of `P` and `A`, respectively, `Pi` is adjusted if it is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and `Ai` is an lvalue reference, in which case the type of `Pi` is changed to be the template parameter type (i.e., `T&&` is changed to simply `T`). [...]

and

> **14.8.2.1 Deducing template arguments from a function call [temp.deduct.call]**
>
> 3 [...] If `P` is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type "lvalue reference to `A`" is used in place of `A` for type deduction. [...]

but no similar exception applies to your scenario.

It's this same principle that renders

```
template <typename T> struct S { };
template <typename T> void f(S<const T>) { }
int main() { f(S<void()>()); }
```

invalid: `const T` cannot be deduced from `void()`, even though `T = void()` would give exactly that result, and calling `f<void()>` would succeed.

Wintermute's deleted answer showed that you can use

> ```
> template <typename... Types>       // vv-- change here
> void print_tuple(const std::tuple<Types...>& value)
> ```

instead: this allows `Types` to be deduced as lvalue references, as rvalue references, or as non-references, depending on the type of `value`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you intend to use `&&` in `std::tuple<Types&&...>` as a universal reference? This is not universal reference; it is rvalue reference and can only bind to rvalues. You can do like this to check what kind of reference it is:

```
template<typename T>
class TD;
```

Then define your template function:

```
template <typename... Types>
void print_tuple(const std::tuple<Types&&...>& value)
{
    TD<decltype(value)> a;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(value) << "," << std::get<1>(value) << std::endl;
}
```

Then you will see the compilation error like:

```
implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<const std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char> &&, int &&> &>'
```

You can see that even for the `int` type, it deduces to be rvalue reference. Rvalue references cannot bind to lvalues. You can try that by calling:

```
int i = 1;
print_tuple(std::forward_as_tuple(i,1)); // error.
```

Therefore, it is correct that `const char(&&)[5]` is deduced, and a string literal cannot be converted to `const char(&&)[5]`. If you call `print_tuple` like:

```
print_tuple(std::forward_as_tuple(string("test"),1));
```

It will work. Now the type is `tuple<string&&, int&&>`.

Comment: Like I commented on the question, if explicitly spelling out the template arguments, as in `print_tuple<const char(&)[5], int>`, it works. This answer is wrong. `T &&` is not necessarily an rvalue reference. If `T` is an lvalue reference, then `T &&` is just `T`. The only problem is that deduction isn't working: when `T &&` is supposed to be `U &`, `T` isn't getting deduced as `U &`, even though it could be.

Comment: @hvd There's nothing in the language which says that `T` could be deduced as `U&` in this context. The conditions for [temp.deduct.call]/3 are not met. A simpler example is `template <class T> void f(const T&&)` which will not bind to lvalues. Unless of course you explicitly specialize the template, which isn't really relevant in a question about template argument deduction.

Comment: @Oktalist It doesn't require specialising the template. It merely requires specifying the template arguments. You can call `f<int&>` with an `int` lvalue expression without any problems, even though deduction will never give you `T = int&`. I just posted an answer with some more details.

Comment: @hvd Excuse me, I meant explicitly specify the template arguments.

Comment: @hvd If you specify `print_tuple<const char(&)[5], int>`, you turn off type deduction. Of course it works because lvalue reference can bind to rvalues. And your answer seems not relevant to the question at all.